# Best way to serialize GeoTIFF in a file to be opened by Python as Numpy array

Tags: python, serialization, file-io, numpy

I have a file in GeoTIFF (geo-referenced TIFF image), which I can load in Python using GDAL and convert into a Numpy array, which my program then processes using the geo-referencing info taken from the file by GDAL.

Since I'd like to remove the GDAL dependency, I plan to serialize the GeoTIFF information to another file format (JSON comes to mind), with the following desireable requirements:

- Small file size;
- Fast access;
- Random-access (slicing) if possible;
- Numpy-friendly (doesn't need a fancy class or another module dependency to decode);
- Simple/straightforward/"human-readable";
- Could be easily used by other scripts in other languages, not cryptic;

JSON would work fine but I'm concerned it's not the smallest neither the fastest access format. Since the array type is `uint16`, binary could be an option. Pickle might be too cryptic. CSV would make difficult to separate the geo-referencing info (corner coordinates and resolution) from the grid values.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Is human readable a necessary requirement (you say later that binary is an option)?

Comment: You'll need to prioritise your requirements. Problem is GeoTIFF has all of these properties, *if* you have GDAL. It seems that implementing a suitable deserializer for a serialization you come up with will be at least as hard as installing GDAL. Sorry, comment isn't useful, but I've spent a while thinking about how you could do this and I can't think of anything sane.

Comment: Human readable could include some easily parsed binary structure (for example, `filename_400x400.dat` for an array with that shape.

Comment: @Hamish Currently I am actually trying to implement a GeoTIFF reader in pure python, also as a learning activity. That would be a one-off workload, since it frees me of having to install GDAL in EVERY machine I could possibly run my script.

Comment: Maybe [tifffile.py](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/code/tifffile.py.html), a pure Python TIFF file reader, could be useful? It's specialized on microscopy formats but is expandable.

Comment: @cgohlke Thanks for the tip! I just took a look, but looks very promising. Gonna check it later, since this pet project is a bit idle currently. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with GeoTIFF information, but for storing flat data I'd highly recommend the [hdf5](http://alfven.org/wp/hdf5-for-python/) format, which has a nice set of python bindings called [h5py](http://h5py.alfven.org/docs-2.0/intro/quick.html). Here's a quick example, showing how easy it is to work with:

```
>>> import h5py
>>> f = h5py.File('data.hdf5')
>>> a = np.arange(12.0).reshape((4,3))
>>> a
array([[  0.,   1.,   2.],
       [  3.,   4.,   5.],
       [  6.,   7.,   8.],
       [  9.,  10.,  11.]])
>>> f.create_dataset('array', data=a)
<HDF5 dataset "array": shape (4, 3), type "<f8">
>>> f['array'].attrs['info'] = 'some data I want to store'
>>> f['array'].attrs['date'] = (6, 21, 2012)
>>> f.close()
>>> f = h5py.File('data.hdf5')
>>> f['array']
<HDF5 dataset "array": shape (4, 3), type "<f8">
>>> f['array'].value
array([[  0.,   1.,   2.],
       [  3.,   4.,   5.],
       [  6.,   7.,   8.],
       [  9.,  10.,  11.]])
>>> f['array'].attrs['info']
'some data I want to store'
>>> f['array'].attrs['date']
array([   6,   21, 2012])
```

Comment: Swaps GDAL dependency for hdf5?

Comment: doh! Yeah I glossed over the "I'd like to remove the dependency" part. Although, I guess it depends on why he wants to remove the GDAL dependency.

Comment: I'm keeping an eye on hdf5, since it is being recurringly mentioned, but the fact is: I am indeed avoiding any extra dependency, specially considering that my GeoTIFF file, and my use of it, are rather simple. Anyway, thank you a lot for your example, I plan to come back when the time comes to use HDF5.